# Custom Bootstrap UI alert with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using `angular-ui-bootstrap` lib in my application. I need to create custom alert with button inside firing modal window.

I have tried two options:

1. Redefine module `angular.module("template/alert/alert.html", [])` from `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`. Didn't work as I didn't manage to implement a button firing popup window.
2. Create a custom module based on `"template/alert/alert.html"` one. Found myself lost in a number of controllers in order to make popup window working.

What is the best approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, you want to add a button to the alert that will launch a modal.

## [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gxk3YmZdkzSBA8mf15p0?p=preview)

The easiest approach is to simply add your button into the alert template.  In the Plunker demo, I copied both the contents of the UI Bootstrap alert and modal demos.  Then I copied the alert template and added it to a script tag on the page.  Inside the standard alert template I added a button as follows:

```
<button ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl" class="btn" ng-class="'btn-' + (type || 'warning')" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>
```

That's an incredibly basic approach, but it should be a good starting point for you.  If I were doing this in production, I would add my custom templates to the template cache instead of using script tags on the page itself and I would create a custom directive for my modal button so that I could pass any relevant information from my alert to my modal instance and do away with having to hard code the ng-controller on the button itself.

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `alert` directive inside the `modal` template:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XJtZWQOqFVc6svECcat0?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately I need to implement an opposite thing. Not a modal with alert inside, but alert with button to fire modal inside.